# I am facing issue while running ionic 2 application that uses map and mapOptions,

Tags: google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

```
return this.loadMap().then(() => {
  const myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(opts.lat, opts.lon);
  const styleArray = [
    {
      featureType: 'poi',
      elementType: 'labels',
      stylers: [
        {visibility: 'off'}
      ]
    }
  ];

  const mapOptions: google.maps.MapOptions = { // this variable gives error
    zoom: opts.zoom,
    minZoom: opts.zoom,
    center: myLatLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    scaleControl: false,
    styles: styleArray,
    zoomControl: false,
    zoomControlOptions: {
      position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
    }
  };

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(mapEl, mapOptions);
  return this.map;
});
}
```

## Run Time Error

Error:

> Type '{ zoom: number; minZoom: number; center: LatLng; mapTypeId: MapTypeId; disableDefaultUI: true; sc...' is not assignable to type 'MapOptions'. Types of property 'styles' are incompatible. Type '{ featureType: string; elementType: string; stylers: { visibility: string; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to type 'MapTypeStyle[]'. Type '{ featureType: string; elementType: string; stylers: { visibility: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'MapTypeStyle'. Types of property 'elementType' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'MapTypeStyleElementType'

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? Did you try isolating the error by removing the `styles` property first? There may be something wrong with your `styleArray`